# Undefined reference to `gst_init'

Tags: cygwin, c++

Люди подскажите начинающему. Беру Gstreamer набор библиотек, компилятор из набора Cygwin.
Ну соответственно редактор Geany. 
Самая начальная программа из main.cpp:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gst_init (&argc, &argv);
            }
```

И Makefile:

```
    HLIB = -I/cygdrive/C/Libs/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/gstreamer-1.0 
-I/cygdrive/C/Libs/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/glib-2.0 
-I/cygdrive/C/Libs/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/glib-2.0/include

        LIB =  -L/cygdrive/C/Libs/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/gstreamer-1.0/static   
    -L/cygdrive/C/Libs/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib/

        all:
            g++ main.cpp -o main.o  $(HLIB) $(LIB)
```

При попытке сборки выдает:

> /cygdrive/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/ccXVu8Fz.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1c):
> undefined reference to `gst_init'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
> status.

Вроде как линковщик ругается. Только не пойму ошибка в чем. В Makefile пути к библиотеке указаны.

*Обновление*

Сделал согласно последним рекомендациям:

1. Перешел в каталог `C:\Libs\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\pkgconfig>.`
2. Сделал оттуда команду `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0.pc`
3. Получил список аргументов:

> -D_REENTRANT -I/c/gstreamer/1.0/x86/include/gstreamer-1.0
> -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include  -L/c/gstreamer/1.0/x86/lib -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lffi -lglib-2.0 -lintl -liconv -lpcre

Затем дописал в Makefile только имена библиотек. Сборка без проблем. Спасибо товарищу AVP и остальным конечно тоже.

Это решение закатайте в ответ у кого позволяет.

Comment: библиотеки похоже прописаны 32битные. А компилируется код в какой разрядности?

Comment: все в 32, и компилятор и библии для 32 разрядных систем.

Answer (score 1):

пересмотрел. Думаю, что ошибка в строке

```
all:
        g++ main.cpp -o main.o  $(HLIB) $(LIB)
```

параметр -o значит, что туда нужно вывести бинарник (туда попадает результирующий файл). А `main.o` - это просто компиляция файла `main.cpp` Видимо, g++ не переносит подобного. Попробуйте ее заменить на что то вида

```
all:
        g++ main.cpp -o gst_demo  $(HLIB) $(LIB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Я глянул в примеры в гугле. Там для сборки всюду используется `pkg-config`.

Эта утилита и строит реальный список аргументов для g++.

Думаю, проблема в том, что у Вас прописаны в Makefile только -L options, а -lконкретное-имя-библиотеки options нет.

Т.е. если `pkg-config` (кстати, м.б. ее надо запускать из bash?) недоступна или gstreamer криво установлен, то надо смотреть что есть в -L каталогах и пытаться сделать options -l... для lib... из этих каталогов.

(для начала можно просто найти в какой из lib... есть gst_init)